# Is there a way to determine when the last user logged in under Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8.1, logging

I came in to work and found that my desktop has moved around and applications have been closed down.  Is there a way to determine when my computer was unlocked?

Comment: The Event Viewer (`eventvwr.msc`) should provide further details.

Comment: I was looking at that, but I couldn't find what I was looking for.  :( That's why I was asking here.  What should I be looking for?

Comment: Did you check the Security category? It should list all logon/logoff and lock/unlock events.

Comment: You'll find related events only if you configured it before. Otherwise, there isn't much you can do.

Comment: How do you configure them?

Comment: See [Windows 8.1 Audit Policy](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Windows-81-Audit-Policy-de62e22f) for instructions to enable security audit / logging.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, you can use Event Viewer to see who logged in. You will probably want to check which event ID to filter on, e.g. 4624 (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947226) and then find the last entries that don't correspond to your username.

Right-click on Security and select "Filter Current Log"

Instead of  enter the Event ID number you want, e.g. 4624

Click OK

Comment: Is there a way to get older dates then today?

Answer (score 1):

You can run `gwmi win32_userprofile -ComputerName computer_name_here` command in powershell which will generate a list of user profiles, paths, SIDs, login time etc. What you should look at are: *LastUseTime* and *LocalPath* variables. Both of those will give you clues as to who logged in and when.

Comment: Is there a way to get the last 10 login times?